# Regex: Lookahead and lookbehind, checking a . (dot) for use as decimal vs full-stop

Tags: .net, regex, numbers, decimal

I've had a good look around the net for an answer to this, but can't seem to get it working.

I have developed the following regex:

```
    (?<![^\d][\\])[\.](?![\d])
```

The objective is to identify any '.' (dots) that have not been escaped or that are part of a decimal number.

ie)

- abc.co.uk, both dots should match
- ab0.co.uk, both dots should match
- abc.0.uk, both dots should match
- abc\.co.uk, only the second dot gets matched
- 0.00, dot should NOT match
- abc0.0.uk, first dot would NOT match (which is an acceptable outcome), second dot should

At moment it works for all the cases above, except:

- abc.0.uk, both dots should match

Any thoughts? It seems the look-behind is working correctly, however the look-ahead is not.

Am sure it'll be an easy one for any Regex gurus!

FYI. I'm developing this in .net 4

Comment: In `abc0.0.uk` second dot should be matched ?

Comment: Sorry, yes the second dot should be matched. stema's answer works great, but if anyone can come up with an even more efficient version, all the better! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

```
(?<![\\\d])\.(?=\d)|(?<=[^\D\\])\.(?!\d)|(?<=[^\d\\])\.(?!\d)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v5jj)

I broke it down in three steps.

1. Match if before is not a escape character and not a digit and behind is a digit.
2. Match if before is not a escape character and a digit and behind is not a digit
3. Match if before is not a escape character and not a digit and behind is not a digit

Comment: Very nice. +1. The trick is to make regex to match things, rather to avoid matching things.

Comment: Beautiful! Seems to work perfectly! I like your approach, didn't occur to me it could take three seperate conditions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Divide task by 2. At first check string is number or not `[^.\d]`. At second choose from rested dots without escape symbol. This approach is much simpler.

Regex from other answer don't cover all cases.